# Recuperar ID passado pela DIV na próxima página

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

Tenho a seguinte classe de CSS junto com o foreach():

```
    <section id="cidades">
        <div class="listacidade">ESCOLHA UMA OPÇÃO</div>
        <ul id="ListandoCidades">
        <? foreach($cidades as $valor){ ?>
            <a href="<? echo base_url('inicial'); ?>">
                <li class="listacidade" id="<? echo $valor->idParametro; ?>">
                    <img src="<? echo base_url(); ?>site/modules/entrada/images/<?=url_title($valor->parametro);?>.jpg" width="250" height="120" alt=""/>
                </li>
            </a>
        <? } ?>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

Estou passando o ID pela `div`. Como eu faço para recuperar ela numa página seguinte?

Comment: Qual ID? Qual página?

Comment: Preciso passar este parametro: id="<? echo $valor->idParametro; ?>", que a próxima página que será /site/index... receberá esse id repassado.

Comment: A próxima página é essa `href="<? echo base_url('inicial'); ?>`?

Comment: Isso mesmo Kadu

Comment: Não consegue passar por ali, tipo `href="<? echo base_url('inicial').'?idParam='.$valor->idParametro; ?>`?

Comment: Não seria essa a minha intenção... Seria ocultar o ID

Comment: no click do link, cria um cookie, redireciona, e na outra pagina le o cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme comentários, para salvar a informação utilize [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) ou [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp):

```
$(document).on('click', '#ListandoCidades a', function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); // Evita que o navegador navegue para o link

   // Pega o ID
   var id = $(this).find('.listacidade').attr('id');

   // Salva o cookie
   document.cookie = 'idParametro='+id;

   // Ou use Local Storage do HTML5
   localStorage.setItem("idParametro", id);

   // Segue o link
   window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');

});
```

Para ler faça o seguinte:

```
// Cookie
var cookies = document.cookie; 
// O retorno é uma string com todos os cookies, será necessário 
// tratá-la para pegar o cookie desejado

// Storage
localStorage.getItem('idParametro');
```

**Obs:** Sua marcação está errada, as tags `li` deve ser filhas diretas da `ul`, e a tag `a` deveria estar dentro das tags `li`. Caso corrija isso, precisará alterar o seletor do parâmetro de `$(this).find('.listacidade')` para `$(this).parent()`.